# How to remove a property from a JavaScript object when using Strict Mode

Tags: javascript

Read this question: [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

However my code uses `'use strict';` in global declaration which means it is present in the whole file.

`delete` statement is forbidden in strict mode (has no effect). [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

How can one delete properties from objects when using strict mode without having to resort to cloning and looping over properties, skipping the one that is to be deleted?

**Update and clarification**:

I need to delete a property from an object before sending it to the server, which complains for unknown properties.

Comment: Your question seems to be founded on a false premise (i.e., that `delete` statements are forbidden in strict mode). What are you *actually* trying to do? What is problem are you *actually* observing? A small, complete code sample that reproduces your issue would be helpful.

Comment: Where does that say that the `delete` statement was forbidden or had no effect?

Comment: @Bergi read the documentation. `Third, strict mode forbids deleting plain names. delete name in strict mode is a syntax error:`

Comment: But a property isn't a plain name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652589/why-is-delete-not-allowed-in-javascript5-strict-mode see the answer

Comment: Yes, things like `with(obj) delete x;` or `window.x = …; delete x` are forbidden. You can still remove properties: `delete obj.x` or `delete window.x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`delete` is **not** forbidden in strict mode.

1. Deleting un-deletable properties in strict mode throws an error. In non-strict mode it fails silently. Either way, it's not possible except for cloning the object.
2. You can't delete plain names; a syntax error is thrown. If the variable is a global variable, you can get around it like so;

   ```
   // Imagine we're global here.
   var foo = 4;

   delete foo; // syntax error
   delete window.foo; // works.
   ```