# How to make Jointjs paper draggable?

Tags: jointjs

I refered [How to make a paper draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431384/how-to-make-a-paper-draggable), however I am stuck at initiate the paper dragging.

I am able to get the handlers and the div as mentioned in the above post, Could you please help in initiating the paper drag.

Code I have tried so far

var draggable;

```
    paper.on('blank:pointerdown', function(evt, x, y) {
        draggable=true;
    });

    $("#paper").on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if(draggable){
            //Make paper draggable and scrollable.
            }
    });

    paper.on('blank:pointerup', function(evt, x, y) {
        draggable=false;
    });
```

Many Thanks