# Prevent JointJS elements from generating off paper

Tags: reactjs, jointjs

I'm using JointJS in a React environment to create a Directed graph from some Neo4j data. My problem is that elements are being generated off the paper [As pictured here, "test6" is generated mostly off the page and "test10" isn't even shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roWDj.png). I would like all elements to be displayed on the paper, without overlapping each other or links if possible.

My paper is defined with only a width dimension set equal to the div width and the div is styled to be 100% width

```
...
width: $('#paper').width(),
...
```

and

```
render(){
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id="paper" style={{width:'100%'}}></div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

The code for generating an element is as follows:

```
function makeElement(node) {
    var maxLineLength = _.max(node.name.split('\n'), function(l) { return l.length; }).length;

    var letterSize = 12;
    var width = 2 * (letterSize * (0.6 * maxLineLength + 1));
    var height = 2 * ((node.name.split('\n').length + 1) * letterSize);

    return new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        id: node.id,
        size: { width: 100, height: height },
        attrs: {
            type:'node',
            text: { 
              text: node.name, 
              'font-size': letterSize, 
              'font-family': 'monospace' },
            rect: {
                width: width, height: height,
                rx: 5, ry: 5,
                stroke: '#555'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I don't have the exact solution yet, but in the meantime I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431384/how-to-make-a-paper-draggable) to make the paper draggable to view all nodes