# Javascript error checker or compiler for strict mode

Tags: javascript

I have this error when running Javastrict.

```
Deleting local variable in strict mode
```

I understood this is because of strict mode.

I am using Titanum and this compiler shows only this message.
So I don't know where the local variable is.

Generally point of view, is there any checker or compiler for javascript?

I would like to find where to occur error.

Comment: It is not Titanium related, but actually strict mode related. You can find more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652589/why-is-delete-not-allowed-in-javascript5-strict-mode

Comment: in general, in strict mode you can't delete variables, only properties. check your code where it's happening and change it

Comment: I see I found where using `delete`. Thank you very much. At first glance, I thought this error means 'please delete local variables'